# Which generated assets should I check in to lock down my package versions in dotnet?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-sdk

In a .NET Core project, `dotnet restore` generates a bunch of files in the `/obj` folder of each project. So, with a solution with the following project files (where `FooLibrary` is a library targeting e.g. `netstandard2.0` and `BarApp` is a console app targeting e.g. `netcoreapp2.0`),

```
FooLibrary
 - Foo.csproj
BarApp
 - Bar.csproj
FooBar.sln
```

running `dotnet restore` in the solution root generates a bunch of files and folders:

```
FooLibrary
 - obj
   - Debug
     - netstandard2.0
       - FooLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs
       - FooLibrary.AssemblyInfoInputs.cache
       - FooLibrary.assets.cache
       - FooLibrary.csproj.CopyComplete
       - FooLibrary.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
       - FooLibrary.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
       - FooLibrary.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
       - FooLibrary.dll
       - FooLibrary.pdb
   - FooLibrary.csproj.nuget.cache
   - FooLibrary.csproj.nuget.g.props
   - FooLibrary.csproj.nuget.g.targets
   - project.assets.json
BarApp
 - obj
   - Debug
     - netcoreapp2.0
       - BarApp.AssemblyInfo.cs
       - BarApp.AssemblyInfoInputs.cache
       - BarApp.assets.cache
       - BarApp.csproj.CopyComplete
       - BarApp.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
       - BarApp.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
       - BarApp.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
       - BarApp.dll
       - BarApp.pdb
       - TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
       - TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
       - TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
       - UserSecretsAssemblyInfo.cs
   - BarApp.csproj.nuget.cache
   - BarApp.csproj.nuget.g.props
   - BarApp.csproj.nuget.g.targets
   - project.assets.json
```

In order to lock down my dependencies and make sure that the package versions in all my dependencies are consistent across team members' machines and build servers, I guess some of these files should be checked in.

Which ones?